# Kotlin: SensorManager works in android studio but not on the phone

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I need help. The gyroscope works in the android studio emulator but when I try to use the apk on my phone the gyroscope doesn't work. The main class where the SensorLisner is defined, is called by a Fragment (). I tried to write a simple gyroscope app in MainActivity class and it works on both the emulator and the phone.Maybe I am doing something wrong in the import/export of the context? [This is how i define sensorManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldafp.png) [This is what the Fragment pass to the Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRBHH.png)

Comment: Please don’t post images of code. Instead, copy-paste the text here. Are your test phone has a gyroscope?

Answer (score 0):

Check your device actually has a gyroscope - a lot of them don't (usually to cut costs). You can call `sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE)` and see if the list it returns is empty, or something like this to see everything your device has:

```
val sm = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL).forEach {
    Log.i("Sensors", "${it.name}: ${it.stringType}")
}
```